# paste, by and data.table in r

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to paste strings from a reshaped dataset. I'm using the data.table package as follows:

```
m<-data.frame(x=rep(c("a","b"),20),y=factor(sample(letters,40,replace=T)))
DT<-data.table(m)
setkey(DT,x)
DT[,paste(y,sep=","),by=x]
```

However, this only gives a new frame quite identical to the original one except for the variable name. I'd like the output to be two concatenated vectors where the variables are pasted together. How can I do this?

Comment: Try `collapse` instead of `sep`.

Comment: That worked wonders---My bad...

Comment: @Misha Just for fun, you could also `as.list` instead of `paste`. That will make a `list` column where each cell itself is a vector. This can sometimes be better than creating a lot of potentially long strings which then might need to be `strsplit` again later. Just as another option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For completeness' sake, an official answer:

If you use `paste(y,collapse=",")` instead, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The `toString(y)` function produced the same result as `paste(y, collapse = ", ")`, I use it as substitute for the longer paste version. So

```
DT[, toString(y), by = x]
```

would yield the outcome

```
#   x                                                         V1
#1: a v, o, q, p, t, c, y, d, n, r, o, k, v, r, t, n, e, f, g, u
#2: b y, j, t, l, w, r, s, w, b, x, h, j, o, k, a, c, r, c, b, e
```

which is the same for paste

```
DT[, paste(y, collapse = ", "), by = x]
```